# Create Options Menu with custom actionbar/toolbar view

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-toolbar, android-optionsmenu

I have already implemented a custom view for my actionbar. Along with that, I also need an OptionMenu.  **Is there any way to still use the default OptionMenu? I dont want to design the entire menu & its functionality myself.**

BTW, my activity extends android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity

---

Code to implement custom view for my actionbar

**custom_action_bar.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
app:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
app:contentInsetStart="0dp">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/custom_B"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp" />
</LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

I included it in my main XML:

```
<include
layout="@layout/custom_action_bar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

For OptionsMenu I put some logs which are never printed

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    Log.i(Constants.APP_NAME, "hello1");
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    Log.i(Constants.APP_NAME, "hello2");
}
```

Comment: I don't know whether you can use the  default OptionMenu with the custom actionBar . But you can create the custom OptionMenu  check this  [link](http://rajeshandroiddeveloper.blogspot.in/2013/07/android-popupwindow-example-in-listview.html)

Comment: What problem are you having? Since you are extending the Toolbar, you should be able to use the Menu. Show what you've tried and what issue you are having.

Comment: I'm gonna take a guess and say you forgot to call setSupportActionBar() in your activity. If you don't call that, then the associated menu methods are never called (because useless). But really you should have posted more of your Activity code.

Comment: @JDenais youre right. I dont know how to mark your comment as the right answer. This was a stupid question. Should I delete it?

Comment: I posted my comment as answer. This is not a stupid question. This point is easily missed in the documentation and it could definitely help others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't forget to call `setSupportActionBar()` in your activity.

Without this call, the associated menu methods are never called because the Activity considers that there is no Toolbar.